# Laplace transform, Bochner integral

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, laplace-transform

I have a quesition about linear operators on a Banach space.

Let $B$ be a real Banach space. $(T_{t})_{t>0}$ is called **strongly continuous contraction semigroup** on $B$ if

- For all $t>0$, $D(T_{t})=B$
- For all $t>0$, $\|T_{t}u\|\leq \|u\|$
- For all $t,s>0$, $u \in B$, $T_{t+s}u=T_{t}T_{s}u$
- $\|T_{t}u-u\|\to0$ as $t \searrow 0$

For $\alpha>0$, We can  define linear operator $G_{\alpha}:B\to B$
\begin{align*}
G_{\alpha}u:=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-\alpha t}T_{t}u\,dt\quad({\rm Bochner\,integral})
\end{align*}
i.e. $(G_{\alpha})_{\alpha>0}$ is the Laplace transform of $(T_{t})_{t>0}$

**My question**:

Let $l \in B^{'}(:={\rm all\,linear\,functional\,on }B)$, $u \in B$, $\alpha>0$, 
\begin{align*}
l(G_{\alpha}u)&=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-\alpha t}l(T_{t}u)\,dt\\
\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-\alpha t}l(\alpha G_{\alpha}u)dt&=\int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-\alpha t}l(T_{t}u)dt\quad(int_{[0,\infty[}e^{-\alpha t}dt=\frac{1}{\alpha})
\end{align*}
By injectivity of Laplace transform, $l(\alpha G_{\alpha}u)=l(T_{t}u),t>0$. By Hahn Banach theorem, $\alpha G_{\alpha}u=T_{t}u$

Is this an inconsistent argument?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You argument is that
$$
               F(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}f(t)dt \\
            \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}\alpha F(\alpha)dt = F(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha t}f(t)dt \\
              \implies \alpha F(\alpha)=f(t)
$$
Does that help you spot your error?

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. I think that I probably could understand that.